# Не работает nginx из интернета

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, raspberry-pi

Настроил nginx и ddns, так что теперь к свому сайту могу подключиться по адресу hypewords.sytes.net, но только если нахожусь со своей raspberry pi в одной локальной сети. Если же подключаться с других выдаёт ошибку ERR_CONECTION_TIMED_OUT. При этом подключение по ssh и к react dev-server с указанием порта, например hypewords.sytes.net:3000 проходит нормально. Из чего я сделал вывод, что проблема именно в nginx.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/hypewords

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /home/pi/<my_domain>/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name <my_domain>.sytes.net;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf (убрал комментарии для читаемости в посте, сам конфиг стандартный)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: С большой вероятностью ваш домашний провайдер блокирует порт 80. Уточните в техподдержке

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо.